# Найти переносы строк, от 3 и более

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как найти 3 и более переносов строк подряд?

Каково выражение будет для preg_replace? Строчку отправляю $_POST

Comment: Можно через str_replace() и count()

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '1



3';
echo preg_replace('/(\s{3,})/m','-', $a);
```

\s - символ переноса строки
{3,} - указание количества повторения этого символа (3 и более раз)
// - границы регулярного выражения
m - [модификатор](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) - указывает что мы ищем на всех строчках а не на одной